# Is there a way to access Bluetooth connected devices in browser?

Tags: javascript, html, web, bluetooth, leap-motion

Is there a way to access Bluetooth connected devices in browser?

I am trying to build a demo system utilizing leap motion for a university project and was planning to build the interface in HTML because leap motion supports JavaScript.

I want the system to have full control over Bluetooth calling on a phone. As most in-car systems currently do; i.e. accept call, decline, make call & view contacts(if possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a trial during January 2017, this is now available in Chrome. Read this article by François Beaufort in developers.google.com: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/07/interact-with-ble-devices-on-the-web

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out the Chrome Bluetooth API, though it appears you need to have a development version of Chrome installed: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/bluetooth

Comment: Thanks, yes I was looking at it a little although it seems poorly supported and quite early stages. Was hoping there was a tried and tested option although its unlikely!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the [Bluetooth Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Bluetooth/getDevices):

```
navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({acceptAllDevices: true}).then(out => console.log(out))
```

Annoyingly it seems like the browser needs Bluetooth permission, and calling the code above fails with `Bluetooth permission has been blocked otherwise.

To allow bluetooth for macOS, add the app to `System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Bluetooth > Plus Button`: [image: MacOS System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Bluetooth > Plus Button]